# IF a a1 matches any cell in B:B then C

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have column D:D with names and column G:G has the same names but with numbers at the end so if D1 matches any cell in G for example G4 I need the data from H4. This is what I have so far

```
    =IF(REGEXMATCH(D2,G2),H2,"")
```

I also tried

```
    =IF(REGEXMATCH(D2:D,G2:G),H2:H,"")
```

[screenshot of sheet]

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Because of business purposes only people with a company email can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In K2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(D2:D), iferror(vlookup(regexreplace(D2:D, "(\s\(\d+\))",), G2:H, 2, 0)),))
```

and see if that works?